# Failed to copy file from host to ansible server

Tags: python, ansible

I'm trying to do a simple process with ansible, however I get failed when trying to run this playbook, I would just like to take the existing file in the user's temporary directory and copy it back to the ansible server inside `etc/ansible/files`

> path and permissions

```
root@ansible:/etc/ansible/files# pwd
/etc/ansible/files
root@ansible:/etc/ansible/files# ls -ltr ../
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  535 mar 27 11:23 ansible.cfg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  188 mar 27 15:41 hosts
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 mar 27 15:42 roles
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 mar 27 15:42 group_vars
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 mar 27 16:59 files
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 mar 27 17:01 playbook
```

> playbook

```
- name: auto_collect_pingprobe
  hosts: "{{ affected_host }}"
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - block:

        - name: 'Copy net connect'
          fetch:
            src: '%temp%\net_connect.cfg'
            dest: '/etc/ansible/files/net_connect.cfg'
            flat: yes

      rescue:
        - fail:
            msg: "Failure detected in playbook"
```

> output

```
fatal: [192.168.238.12]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "failed to transfer file to \"/etc/ansible/files/net_connect.cfg\""
}

TASK [fail] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/playbook/GEN_AUTO_COLLECT_HOST_AVAILABLE.yml:22
fatal: [192.168.238.12]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failure detected in playbook"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things may be going on.

1. You may not have root permissions on the controlled node, ensure that you are using the `--become` flag when invoking the notebook (or use equivalent privilege escalation).
2. The `%temp%` variable may not be being read from the environment. Try replacing the `src` string with `'{{ lookup("env", "temp") }}\net_connect.cfg'`.

Comment: I test, returned this msg: " FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Path \\echo.txt is not found"}"

Comment: Is the `%temp%` variable defined in your environment? From the error it looks like you were looking for `%temp%\\echo.txt` and `%temp%` was undefined. Try `set temp=<YOUR_PATH>` in your shell to set the var (on Windows).

Comment: Ok, I'm going to do some tests